# Отступы после применения layout_weight

Tags: android, c#, xaml, xamarin, разметка

В портретной ориентации появляются непонятные пробелы над и под картинками. В альбомной ориентации все нормальною. Как их можно убрать? Мне просто надо две картинки без никаких пробелов. Может вместо LinearLayout что то другое применить?

Код и скриншоты

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:weightSum="100">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/i1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_weight="50" />
    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/i2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_weight="50" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/i3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView3" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Портретная]

[image: Альбомная, без пробелов над и под изображениями]

Comment: Поиграйтесь с параметром `scaleType`. Начните с `center"

Comment: для imageview используйте атрибут `android:adjustViewBounds = "true"` - подгонять размеры изображения под размер контейнера

Comment: Оооо, спасибо тебе большое pavlofff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

для `ImageView` используйте атрибут `android:adjustViewBounds = "true"` - подгонять размеры изображения под размер контейнера.

Например:

```
<ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/i1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
```