# Изображение в ImageView по ширине экрана

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

Необходимо чтобы изображение в ImageView  отображалось по ширине экрана. Чтобы невозможно было уменьшить его меньше этого размера. Чтобы ImageView не генерировал дополнительные пустые области. 
Пробовал `ImageView .setCropToPadding(true);` но нет эффекта.
[image: устройство]

При загрузке должна отображаться область обведённая красным. Размеры Image по ширине соответствуют ширине экрана.

```
<TouchImageView.TouchImageView
            android:id="@+id/touchIV"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="matrix"/>
```

```
    ...
    int textViewX =textView.getMeasuredWidth();
    int textViewY = textView.getMeasuredHeight();
    Bitmap bitmap;
    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(textViewX,int textViewY,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c =new Canvas(bitmap);            
    textView.layout(0,0,textViewX ,textViewY );
    textView.draw(c);
    constraintLayout.removeView(textView);

    final   TouchImageView touchImageView;
    touchImageView = (TouchImageView) findViewById(R.id.touchIV);
    touchImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    touchImageView.setCropToPadding(true);
```

Comment: Так должно быть по ширине экрана или как в красной области?

Comment: @Valgaal Красная область - это та часть Image,  которая должна отображаться в самом начале при старте активности. Получается должно быть как в красной области. По-моему это и есть по ширине, или я что-то путаю? Сейчас ImageView  при старте отображает всю картинку, загоняя её и по ширине и по высоте, от этого генерируются пустые области по краям. Мне нужно чтобы их не было.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/730339/177345

Comment: очень путанное объяснение, если вам не нужны "пустые области", то android:scaleType="fitXY"

Answer (score 0):

android:layout_height="match_parent" растянет ImageView на ширину родителя, обрати внимание не Изображение растянет и именно ImageView.
Вот варианты отображения изображения https://robots.thoughtbot.com/android-imageview-scaletype-a-visual-guide

Посмотри про Layout weight например: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fSIFpquL4Vc

У тебя на рисунке якобы 2 view, если к ним применить weight = 1, то они должны будут занимать ровно по половине.

Comment: У меня в коде же написано `android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" android:scaleType="matrix" 76 1`

Comment: а какой у тебя родитель для ImageView? Попробуй например linearlayout и попробуй эту строчку
touchImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);

Comment: Там с родителем всё в порядке. Изображение масштабируется нормально. Проблема только в самом ImageView  с этими ненужными пробелами. Не пойму как запретить уменьшать изображение до таких пределов. Да, я пробую разные ScaleType  и другие настройки, но это как пальцем в небо.

Comment: Если я правильно понял то ты хочешь растянуть изображение по ширине экрана?
1. Попробуй залить backgorund нужного ImageView каким нибудь цветом и ты увидишь действительно ли ImageView растягивается на весь экран. 
2. ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY должен растянуть изображение на весь ImageView. 
3. Ты можешь попробовать применить touchImageView.setMinimumWidth и   touchImageView.setMinimumHeight. 
4. Попробуй закрасить родителя, посмотри занимает ли родитель всю ширину экрана.